# What can I use redundant/spare AGM batteries for?

Tags: battery, solar

In [my off-grid cabin](https://www.airbnb.no/rooms/18731440) I currently have a single [258 Ah (C24) Concorde PVX-2580L](http://www.sunxtender.com/solarbattery.php?id=11) battery, with a 150 Ah spare (and generator) for backup situations where the main runs flat.

As I frequently see the voltage drop below 12.1V (i.e. *the 50% mark*) in the winter time, I have bought a pair of 2580's to double my available energy. These are of a different age and series than the one I currently have, and as one is not supposed to mix different AGM batteries on the same circuit, I am now exploring how I can make good use of them.

One thing I just came across is DC-DC chargers, such as [this one from Victron](https://www.victronenergy.com/dc-dc-converters/orion-tr%20smart). That would allow me for 120$ to charge a battery using the new batteries. That would effectively create a new circuit, so it would easily be under-utilized, if I didn't use that circuit much. I would also need to find space for the behemoth battery the 2580 is :)

Any other input on how I could make good use of the redundant batteries?

Comment: Before thinking about drawing from two AGM battery banks, how were you planning to get them charged to capacity?

Comment: @Jeeped I have solar panels charging them, with a generator + 50A charger for the winter time.

Answer (score 2):

I would not charge a battery from other batteries; that is insane because it creates conversion losses for no good reason.

However, when one battery is charging, it is fine to tap that energy to charge another battery, using any of a variety of methods.  Like any charging, this should be a proper charge controller, not just a diode array.

You don't want to be in a situation of leaving a battery partially discharged for any longer than necessary, because that ages a lead-acid battery.

### Lead-acid batteries are a perishable asset

A lot of people, especially who live out in the country and have barn space, don't throw stuff out.  They keep it around forever, on the logic that it "saves having to buy it again".  *Do not do that with lead-acid batteries*.  A lead-acid battery dumped in the back of the barn for 5 years will be dead as a stone when you go to use it.

Your only options for "surplus" batteries which are still working is a) sell it promptly to someone who can put it to work, or b) put it to work yourself.

So either get rid of it right now... or modify your system to make use of its capacity on a daily basis.  Every battery is an addition, because discharge wears lead-acid batteries, and the rate of wear is an exponential function of discharge depth.  Draining 2 batteries to 55% full is much worse for total-cost-of-ownership than draining 3 batteries to 70% full.

### "Spare for when one runs flat" is also a fail

Similarly, the idea of running one battery pack dead, then switching to the next pack, is a bankrupt idea as far as total cost of ownership. Running a lead-acid pack to failure is *absolutely brutal* on service life of the battery.  A car starting battery is destroyed by 5-10 dips to dead.  A battery specifically for solar is destroyed by some dozens of such dips, and worn/damaged/capacity reduced by every single dip.

Again, for best use of the batteries, you want to pull them down as evenly as is practicable.  80-100% won't matter, so pull A to 80%, then B to 80%, then C to 80%, then A to 70%, B to 70%, C to 70%, etc.

Even better, have a smart battery merger/controller that blends all packs together, drawing them down equally; however this requires some intelligence - diodes alone are not enough.  (Also diodes take a *bare minimum* 0.2V drop and most diodes are more like 0.8% -- that's 2-6% of total battery capacity being wasted in heating up diodes.) A manual string of switches (B on, A off) would be more efficient.

### Physical topology is also a consideration

If your house is spread out, and 60% of your load is in one place, 25% in another place and 15% in another place... it may be better to distribute your packs around the house so that the batteries are near the loads, rather than "wheeling" (hauling) 12V over long distances.  Voltage drop bites 12V *very hard*: with only 1/10 the voltage of 120V, it has 10x the *voltage* drop, which means 100x the *power* drop. You can end up losing a significant fraction of battery capacity to wiring losses, unless you're up on the ought-sizes of wire.

Comment: Thank you for a full-bodied answer. I am not sure what to do of it, though, meaning you seem to talk about stuff I have no intention of doing or have done (like draining the batteries on a regular basis), and I am left just as clueless as to what to _actually do_ after reading (except the bit about just selling it, which is decent advice). I rent out my cabin and people do dumb things like draining the main battery and then I keep a fully charged spare for those rare cases. At least the Concorde batteries are best-in-class when it comes to handling deep cycling (though not indestructible!).

Comment: I am not an electrical engineer, so talking of [diodes is a bit above my head](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode). The _smart battery merger/controller_ concept does sound extremely interesting, but I have never heard talk of that in any off-grid forums. Do you have more info on that?

Comment: The "smart battery merger/controller" seems like the holy grail for PV home owners. That this doesn't exist makes me think that there's a bit more complexity to it than on first look. I am a programmer, so the feedback logic seems OK to implement, but I have been totally unable to find anything resembling the description.

Comment: @oligofren, would it be an option to sell *all* your current batteries, and just get one large one (or equivalently, two or more identical smaller ones in parallel)? That would likely be cheaper, and perform better, than combining unmatched ones with some sort of smart controller -- and that's also why such controllers are hard to find.

Comment: And since you mention you have a generator anyway, I'd recommend using that as the backup, rather than a fully charged spare, for the reasons of self-discharge and aging that Harper discusses

Comment: @oligofren All viable strategies for managing batteries depend on the owner *having skin in the game*; skill, control and incentive to use the battery responsibly. Completely unrealistic in a rental unit.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica There are not any substantially larger batteries on the market. The Concorde Sun Extender 2580 is rated at 305Ah at C100 and 12V. The largest alternative I could find is 350Ah at C100 and 12V. So I have about 700Ah at C100 for the pair I have. The suggestion to just get rid of the spare ones I have is probably the best. By the time they are ready to be replaced, lithium batteries will have an unmatched price/performance anyway (prices are expected to drop by an additional 70% in the next 5 years).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Renting it out has gone surprisingly well, actually! I have just had one total depletion incident in 3 years. Everyone gets a [12 page booklet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1BHE_6Jk06KrZ35Exl-5l3R64ATYP9rm8ZKgP7ono-To/export?format=pdf) to help them use it responsibly, so people recharge the batteries every day when they show < 70%. The only problem I have is that I would like to use the generator less, hence the upgrade in capacity.

Comment: @oligofren, in that case, you can parallel batteries if you want additional capacity -- the only catch is they have to be identical; same brand, same age, same number of cycles, etc., in order to work well without any fancy balancing electronics.

Comment: @NateS-ReinstateMonica Your last statement is what I have always heard: do not mix different capacities/age. Today I browsed several answers on the electrical engineering StackExchange and it seems it is far from that cut and dry. As long as the chemistry is the same, you have no shorts or heavy sulfation, they are in working condition, and the batteries are _connected in parallel_, it does not matter that they are of different capacity. Would you agree? In that sense my best option seems to be to add all four batteries in parallel, as they are all above 90% capacity of new.

Comment: @oligofren, that's true *if* they're otherwise exactly the same, but since yours are different brands and ages, they're not.  Different brands will sometimes have different proprietary additives to the electrolyte, which can affect the internal resistance and rate of self-discharge, and small differences in age can affect this too.  It would work, in the sense that you could run them that way and nothing would blow up, but there's a good chance your weaker batteries will be holding back your stronger ones.